# Querying nested document structure in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am trying to query below document structure

```
{
 _id: '7ja9sjkadja',
 parent: {
     parentName: 'Super',
     firstGenerations: [
         {
            name: 'First Generation',
            secondGenerations: [
            {
                 name: 'Second Generation 1',
                 value: 'Married'
            },

            {
                 name: 'Second Generation 2',
                 value: 'Single'
            },
            {
                 name: 'Second Generation 3',
                 value: 'Single'
            }

           ]
         }


     ]
 }

}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  firstGenerationName: 'First Generation',
  totalCount: 3
  values: [
     {
        categoryName: 'Married (1)',
        count: 1,
        firstGenerationName: 'First Generation'
     },

     {
        categoryName: 'Single (2)',
        count: 2,
        firstGenerationName: 'First Generation'
     }

    ]

  }
```

Query tried by me:

db.generations.aggregrate([

```
{ $project: { 'firstGenerations': '$parent.firstGenerations'} },
{ $unwind: '$firstGenerations'},
{ $unwind: '$firstGenerations.secondGenerations'}
{
   $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      count: { 'sum': '$secondGenerations.value' },
      firstGenerationName: { $first: '$firstGenerations.name'} 
   }
}

])
```

I am able to unwind properly but not able to club group functionality by taking one value from parent array and count from second array.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to run `$group` twice to get inner counts first:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$parent"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$parent.firstGenerations"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$parent.firstGenerations.secondGenerations"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                fgName: "$parent.firstGenerations.name",
                sgValue: "$parent.firstGenerations.secondGenerations.value"
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.fgName",
            values: {
                $push: {
                    categoryName: { $concat: [ "$_id.sgValue", " (", { $toString: "$count" }, ")" ] },
                    count: "$count",
                    firstGenerationName: "$_id.fgName"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            firstGenerationName: "$_id",
            values: 1,
            totalCount: { $sum: "$values.count" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vSCWCUloO5y)